# PHP str_pos embed Video

Tags: php, youtube, strpos

The problem is, this method work only for one video.
And is a text after the link (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID nice video!) then doensn't works.

```
<?php
                if (strpos($content, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=') !== false) {
                    $content = str_replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$id", '<object width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $id . '&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1?rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $id . '&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1?rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"></embed></object>', $content);
                } else if (strpos($content, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=') !== false) {
                    $content = str_replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$id", '<object width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"><param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/' . $id . '&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1?rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/' . $id . '&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1?rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"></embed></object>', $content);
                }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need a regex, not simple replacement.

Comment: `if(preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/", $content, $matches)) {
                                echo "Youtube";}` doensn't work, can you help me?

Comment: <?php
$youtube_regexp = "/^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)\/(?:watch\?(?=.*v=([\w\-]+))(?:\S+)?|([\w\-]+))$/";
$urls = $content;
$urls = explode("\n", $urls);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
preg_match($youtube_regexp, $url, $matches);
$matches = array_filter($matches, function($var) {
return($var !== '');
});
if (sizeof($matches) == 2) {
echo "YT ID: " . $matches[1];
}
}
?> 

doesn't work... I need help. :(